# How do i compare a resultset object with a string?

Tags: java, jdbc, properties

I want to compare the databases fetched into a ResultSet object with a database stored in properties file.If the database match with dbname of properties file it will print xxx.I am providing the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,   SQLException {
Properties props=new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("/home/core/Desktop/Java/Sample Netbeans   Projects/Project/PropStoreDb/StoreDbNameProps.properties"));        
Class.forName(props.getProperty("db.driver"));
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("show databases");
    if(rs.next()){
        for(int i=1;i<=rs.getRow();i++){
            if(rs.getString(i).equals(props.getProperty("db.dbname")))
            {
                System.out.println("xxx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the properties file

```
db.dbname=mydb
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to

```
while(rs.next()){
if(rs.getString(1)!=null && rs.getString(1).equals(props.getProperty("db.dbname")))
            {
                System.out.println("xxx");
            }
}
```

There is no need of a `for` loop. The query `show databases;` will return a resultset with a single column.so, you can get the data using `rs.getString(1)` since column id starts from 1